# react context в ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, context

можно ли использовать React Context для организации взаимодействия компонентов
которые не являются один предком другому и не являются потомками другого компонента
то есть полностью независимы друг от друга ?

Comment: Но есть же какой-то родительский компонент?

Comment: стандартный <div id="root"></div> -но это же не компонент а в нем допустим два независимых компонента

Comment: Добавьте лучше минимальный код, чтобы было ясно что к чему

Comment: вопрос концептуальный - как организовать взаимодействие между двумя независимыми компонентами - то есть чтобы изменение стейт в одном вызывало изменеие стейт в другом - какой подход использовать ? можно ли этого добиться через контекст

Comment: @Mik можно, конечно. Но в контексте могут быть и другие вещи, которые не относятся к этому и тогда будут лишние компоненты ререндериться. Попробуйте создать компонент-обертку для этих двух.

Comment: @entithat не нужна обертка, можно и через контекст с хуком useContext  тогда рендериться будут только те компоненты которые зависимы от стейта контекста.

Comment: @Александр, в контексте тоже много вещей может быть независимых. Уже представляю как половина приложения будет каждый раз обновляться.